# Как правильно написать макрос?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, define, c11

Есть 3 основных #define: **LIST_SIZE_T** , **LIST_SIZE_MIN** , **LIST_SIZE_MAX**

нужно что бы при задании **типа** в ..._T макросы MIN и MAX автоматически определялись с нужным числом и длиной.

К примеру есть тип int и есть макросы INT_MIN И INT_MAX, нужно сделать тоже самое при том, что кастомный тип будет повторять существующие стандартные и что-бы _MIN и _MAX не выставлять вручную.

Мой, естественно неработающий, код:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define LIST_SIZE_T unsigned
#define LIST_SIZE_MIN 0

#define CONCAT(X, Y, Z) X##Y##Z 
#define UINT_MAX(X) CONCAT(UINT, X, _MAX)
#define LIST_SIZE_MAX UINT_MAX(sizeof(LIST_SIZE_T)*8)
```

P.S. Тип, задаваемый в ..._T, всегда целочисленный без знаковый.

Comment: Ничего не понятно что вам нужно и зачем.

Comment: У меня есть разные коллекции (Стек, очередь, список и т.д.).
Для каждой заведён свой .h и .c .
У каждой есть свои ..._MIN, ..._MAX, ..._T .
Я могу до #include "коллекция" определить эти дефайны и тогда коллекция в программе будет с кастомным размером.
Я не хочу вызывать по 3 дефайна на каждую коллекцию, а вызывать только 1 и что бы MIN и MAX сами подстраивались, в зависимости от того какой я тип выберу, а типов не много, я в P.S. описал.

Comment: ¿Может использовать С++, не?

Comment: Почему бы не написать просто `#define LIST_SIZE_MAX (sizeof(LIST_SIZE_T) * 8)`?  / А м. б. лучше будет так `#define LIST_SIZE_MAX(t) (sizeof(t) * 8)`. / Возможно также, вместо **8**, вам более подойдет `CHAR_BITS` из limits.h / Впрочем, без глубокого понимания того, что именно и для каких "условий эксплуатации" вы ваяете, посоветовать хорошее решение невозможно

Comment: @user7860670 , Нет, нужно реализовать библиотеку именно на Си. Мне очень понравилась концепция в C# System.Collection.Generic и хочу попробовать сделать это тут, естественно не на отъе...ись, что бы и код прилично выглядел, и работало шустренько на любой картошке, поэтому и пришёл сюда с таковым вопросом.
Перед запуском проекта хочется указывать максимальные и минимальные значения коллекциям, что бы случайно программа в разнос не ушла

Comment: @avp , В идеале что бы к моменту компиляции программа знала, что это за константы и не требовала их вычислять. Ведь, например, при каждом добавлении требуется вычислить не является ли коллекция заполнена. а таких проверок могут быть миллионы в секунду. Либо как-то заменить тяжкие операции на более простые, например с переполнением и т.д.
Вообще интерес ближе к спортивному, не журить же меня за то, что я пытаюсь написать грамотно)

Comment: @YoungSideways, величина **`sizeof(T)`**  (и следовательно ее произведение на константу) как раз **известна во время компиляции**

Comment: @avp , А на каком моменте она вычисляется?

Comment: После того, как препроцессор подставит значения макросов в виде текста в программу, где-то после синтаксического анализа, перед генерацией object кода.  / [Значение оператора sizeof вычисляется во время компиляции и считается константой. Оно может быть использовано везде, где требуется константное значение](https://it.wikireading.ru/35795)

Answer (score 0):

Если всегда целочисленный беззнаковый, то можно по-простому, без многоэтажных константных выражений:

```
#if !defined(LIST_SIZE_T) // Для тестирования: сс -DLIST_SIZE_T="unsigned char"
    #define LIST_SIZE_T unsigned short
#endif

// Содержимое my_list.h 
#if !defined(MY_LIST_H_0132_)
#define MY_LIST_H_0132_

#if !defined(LIST_SIZE_T)
    #error "LIST_SIZE_T должен быть определён до #include \"my_list.h\""
#endif

#define LIST_SIZE_MIN 0
#define LIST_SIZE_MAX ((LIST_SIZE_T)-1)

struct my_list_h_0132_ {
    char assert[LIST_SIZE_MIN < LIST_SIZE_MAX ? 0 : -1];
};

#endif // !defined(MY_LIST_H_0132_)

// Тест
#include <stdio.h>

#define MKSTR(D) #D
#define STR(D)  MKSTR(D)

int main()
{
    printf("LIST_SIZE_T=%s\n", STR(LIST_SIZE_T));
    printf("sizeof(LIST_SIZE_T)=%zu\n", sizeof(LIST_SIZE_T));
    printf("LIST_SIZE_MAX=0x%llx\n", (unsigned long long)LIST_SIZE_MAX);
    return 0;
}
```